# Powershell Get-Random with dates blocked with "this script contains malicious content"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm generating files for a lab environment with random dates for creation, modification, and last access. This has been working fine until very recently when Powershell/VSCode started blocking the script because it contains "malicious code". A few days ago, this code ran just fine:

```
$MaximumDate = Get-Date
[datetime]$CreationDate = $MaximumDate.AddYears(-10).Ticks
[datetime]$ModificationDate = Get-Random -Minimum $CreationDate.Ticks -Maximum ($MaximumDate.AddSeconds(-1)).Ticks
[datetime]$LastAccessDate = Get-Random -Minimum $ModificationDate.Ticks -Maximum $MaximumDate.Ticks
```

When running it since yesterday, it throws the following error:

```
At line:3 char:1
+     [datetime]$ModificationDate = Get-Random -Minimum $CreationDate.T ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This script contains malicious content and has been blocked by your antivirus software.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptContainedMaliciousContent
```

[This blog post](https://evotec.xyz/import-module-this-script-contains-malicious-content-and-has-been-blocked-by-your-antivirus-software/) indicates it is Windows Defender causing this. For that poster, waiting for a new update solved it, but I'm not too keen on having to rely on specific Windows Updates for this to work. Here are some interesting finds.

This code is blocked:

```
[datetime]$ModificationDate = Get-Random -Minimum $CreationDate.Ticks -Maximum ($MaximumDate.AddSeconds(-1)).Ticks
```

This code works:

```
$Ticks = Get-Random -Minimum $CreationDate.Ticks -Maximum ($MaximumDate.AddSeconds(-1)).Ticks
[datetime]$ModificationDate = $Ticks
```

But if you put that working code in an if/else statement, it fails again:

```
if(any condition you like){
    $Ticks = Get-Random -Minimum $CreationDate.Ticks -Maximum ($MaximumDate.AddSeconds(-1)).Ticks
    [datetime]$ModificationDate = $Ticks
}
else{
    $Ticks = Get-Random -Minimum $MinimumDate.Ticks -Maximum $CreationDate.Ticks
    [datetime]$ModificationDate = $Ticks
}
```

There seems to be something with the Get-Random that VSCode does not like and thinks that it is malicious. The code runs in Powershell but is blocked when running it from VSCode. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

**EDIT:** And for clarification, I'm running the code with a user that is a local admin, domain admin, and running both PS and VSCode as admin, Get-ExecutionPolicy shows "Bypass" so it should not be an issue of permissions.

Comment: If the code was working and you changed nothing, then stops working then the only option is that your or the user environment has changed. There is nothing PowerShell can do about that. You must find what changed and either roll back those changes or retool your code.  There are no features in code editors (VS. VSCode, ISE,  et all) or script engines/parsers which flag code as malicious. Unless you have an extension that provides such a feature, otherwise, code is handed off to the engine which loads into memory which Windows OS and threat management then act on.

Comment: Quickly testing your code in a pristine Win10VM, generate no errors or AV or malicious code warnings. So, I cannot reproduce what you are seeing. This is an Anit-Virus control. You have already found this point to date. So, you either have to wait for the update or get exclusions set by your AV admin for what you are doing. Developers do this often for compilers which do plenty of memory manipulation in build and CI/CD cycles. Now, why you are only seeing this when you run your code from VSC is a mystery. I am going to assume when you say you tan in PS, that was not from the ISE?

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Yes, since the only other reference I could find was that 2018 blog post about Windows Defender being the culprit then I assume it must be a recent Windows Update. I verified the code in ISE that it worked, in pure PS it doesn't. What I don't understand would be why running each command one line at a time works fine but running the together does not. As you can probably tell I'm not a developer :) I'll see about exclusions with our IT department, thank you!

Comment: No worries. Depending on how aggressive they set your AV checks, it could be something andsimple as serialization speeds or randomizations.  Compilers do this stuff all the time, hence why devs need the exclusions. Extremely fast file writes/serialization (RAM or disk), often trigger AV solutions as indicators of [`Resource Exhaustion attacks`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_exhaustion_attack), similar to what DDOS attacks do. If you put a pause, say 1 - 2 seconds between your writes, you may not get this AV alert. Again, depending on how aggressive the AV is set.

Comment: The other thing to remember is that you are doing, file attribute manipulation, another AV trigger point, especially when it's down at CPU speeds. If the lab is not internet-connected, the risk is minimal and they should allow you to do this. But, hey, different companies and their risk management/security policies,  rule th day.

Comment: OH, that might actually be it! I tried to add some random bs code that really didn't do anything between the lines and that made it run, so it might be that it's too fast. For the file attribution manipulation, I haven't even gotten to that bit yet. The above code just stores datetimes to memory to later be used when creating dummy files with Set-ItemProperty, so the only thing going on is within Powershell so far. Good information, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Unfortunately, I sometimes get the error when just running one single line. If I run the Get-Random for datetime ticks as min/max values it works, but trying to assign that to a variable fails. I'm beyond confused at this point but I will wait for the next Windows Defender update to see if that is the reason for all this.

Comment: I also had this problem today with a simple batch script running a PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: Interesting.  I'll have to mess around more in my lab, but, it could be obviously something unique in your environment since I could not repro your original use case on several machines in my lab all using different default installed/default settings AV solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Windows Update.

As suspected, the resolution in the Evotec link seems to be the culprit. After the recent-most Windows Update, randomising a datetime and assigning it to a variable no longer triggers the "malicious code" error.